# Turn Laptop hotspot on using java

Tags: java

Is there any way to turn on laptop hotspot using java? I want to transfer files by making a local network which can be established by connecting two laptops which will require to turn the hotspot on on one computer and connecting other computer by that hotspot.

Comment: Sure, what have you tried so far?  What code are you currently having problems with?  This is far from a simple program to throw together and will vary based on the operating systems on the client/server.  You might be able to get a start from an open source project but Stack Overflow isn't a place to request free custom software.

Comment: I thought that I could use command line then execute those commands in java. I searched on the internet about the command "netsh wlan start hostednetwork" , but when I ran this command it is showing the hosted network could not be started, The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation. I also tried to go to device manager to enable "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter"  but I don't have this in my device manager under network adapters.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be specific to your laptop and OS, but the general solution is to figure out how to turn the hotspot on using command line and then execute the command in java. There's a guide on how to do that here:

https://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/execute-operating-system-commands-using-runtime-exec-methods

Comment: I want to perform this on windows 10 , and about command line my laptop have hosted network supported as no , so is there a way if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Java itself cannot change settings like that and cannot easily make modifications outside of the JVM. try to find a library that can do this if you cant from the command line.  If you really want to do this though with just pure java, then use robot class to access the settings like a human would.